# Magento insert decimal value in database

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin

I have one custom module.
There is one field which is decimal number.
But on saving it doesn't store decimal value.
Like **`saving`** : `1.23`     **`after_saving`** : `1.00`
When I add the value from phpmyadmin it gets added and the same value is retreived and after that if the data is saved it again repeats :- **`saving`** : `1.23`     **`after_saving`** : `1.00`
Please help .

Comment: Hi, You want to float value or want to access the integer part of that value?

Comment: @Chiragit007 : I want to save whole decimal number e.g : 1.23.This value should be saved.Thanks

Comment: Can you show the functions `getEscapedValue` and `roundPrice` from `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php` and `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php`  here

Comment: Hi, We have same problem as you have faced. So, can you please tell us how can be fix this? Waiting for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @yogus for giving hint.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php
```

So in controller `SaveAction()`

have added

```
$data['sorter'] = number_format($data['sorter'], 2, null, '');
```

`$data['sorter']` --> This is value coming in post.